# asp create a div element with label and link button on code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This my code,

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>&nbsp;Application Number
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Div element to be created">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server">Language1</asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <asp:linkbutton ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:linkbutton>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i need to create the third div element from code behind is it possible?
if selected language count is 2, then i need to create 2 div for both languages.

Answer (score 0):

Place a *runat="server"* tag into the *div*. Then you can modify its contents from the code.